# How can I merge these two into one function of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to allow users to search and filter a HTML table.

```js
function searchFilter(event) {
  var filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  var rows = document.querySelector("#filterTable tbody").rows;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var secondCol = rows[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var fourthCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var sixthCol = rows[i].cells[5].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var seventhCol = rows[i].cells[6].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var eighthCol = rows[i].cells[7].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (secondCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || thirdCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || fourthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || sixthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || seventhCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || eighthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      rows[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('#driverSearch').addEventListener('keyup', searchFilter, false);
```

```html
<section id="chronology">
  <h2 id="chronology">Chronology</h2>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" id="driverSearch" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <table class="chronology sortable full-width" id="filterTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Year</th>
          <th scope="col">Grand Prix</th>
          <th scope="col">Circuit</th>
          <th scope="col">Race No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Constructor</th>
          <th scope="col">Chassis</th>
          <th scope="col">Engine</th>
          <th class="align-r" scope="col">Start</th>
          <th class="align-r" scope="col">Win margin</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">1</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Canada"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Canada.png" alt="Canada flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-canadian-grand-prix/">Canada</a></td>
          <td>Montreal</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">4.343s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">2</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="USA"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/United-States.png" alt="USA flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-united-states-grand-prix/">USA</a></td>
          <td>Indianapolis</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">1.518s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">3</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Hungary"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Hungary.png" alt="Hungary flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-hungarian-grand-prix/">Hungary</a></td>
          <td>Hungaroring</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">0.715s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">4</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Japan"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Japan.png" alt="Japan flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-japanese-grand-prix/">Japan</a></td>
          <td>Fuji</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">8.377s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">5</th>
          <td>2008</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Australia"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Australia.png" alt="Australia flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2008-world-championship/2008-australian-grand-prix/">Australia</a></td>
          <td>Melbourne</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-23</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">5.478s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">6</th>
          <td>2008</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Monaco"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Monaco.png" alt="Monaco flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2008-world-championship/2008-monaco-grand-prix/">Monaco</a></td>
          <td>Monte Carlo</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-23</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="third-hl align-r">3</td>
          <td class="align-r">3.064s</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

In the third column I am having some trouble. This column contains both img tags and anchor tags. Within the img tags the source link contains date formats such as: /uploads/2018/09/Spain.png.

The second column of my table is a year column. When users filter the table by year every year works apart from 2018. Because every image was uploaded in 2018, if a user wants to filter the table to show only 2018 entries the table shows every row despite the year. For example, the year 2002 will show up when you search for 2018. I know why, it's because the 2018 in the url is being accounted for.

I need just the text from the anchor, which led me to the following code:

```
rows[0].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent
```

If I replace `var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();`with

```
rows[0].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent
```

the 2018 problem goes away. If you search for 2018 only results with 2018 in the second column are shown. However, if you search for any text from the third column the filter returns no results at all.

So, can `rows[0].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent` be added to the initial function in anyway to make the two work together? Or is there another way for me to do this?

Comment: You mean now if we search from 3rd column it won't works. Like if we search `Canada` it won't show any result?

Comment: That's right. The year part gets fixed but searching for country names yields no results. I need to the two different pieces of code to work together if possible.

Comment: Geeze, this is brutal. Look at [DataTables (a free plugin)](https://datatables.net/) and you get universal search out of the box...

Comment: Brutal as in way too much code for the desired result? Thanks for the recommendation. Looks like it would be more than useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be slightly easier to iterate over the cell data and if there's no match (I'm using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to return a boolean if there's text in any cell that matches the filter) hide the row. That way you don't have to manually check each cell with its index.

```js
// Cache the rows outside of the searchFilter function
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#filterTable tr");

// Add a reset function that removes the hide class
// from all the rows
function reset() {
  rows.forEach(row => row.classList.remove('hide'));
}

function searchFilter(event) {

  const filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();

  // If the string is empty reset
  if (!filter) {
    reset();
  } else {

    // Otherwise iterate over each row
    rows.forEach((row, i) => {

      // Grab all the cells from the row
      const cells = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'));

      // Use `some` to check each text of the cell
      // (note you have to use `trim` to get rid
      // of whitespace otherwise an exact match won't be found
      const foundFilter = cells.some(cell => {
        const cellText = cell.textContent.trim().toUpperCase();
        return cellText === filter;
      });

      // If a match was found remove the hide class,
      // otherwise add it
      if (foundFilter) {
        row.classList.remove('hide');
      } else {
        row.classList.add('hide');
      }
    });
  }

}

document.querySelector('#driverSearch').addEventListener('keyup', searchFilter, false);
```

```css
.hide { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<section id="chronology">
  <h2 id="chronology">Chronology</h2>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" id="driverSearch" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <table class="chronology sortable full-width" id="filterTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Year</th>
          <th scope="col">Grand Prix</th>
          <th scope="col">Circuit</th>
          <th scope="col">Race No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Constructor</th>
          <th scope="col">Chassis</th>
          <th scope="col">Engine</th>
          <th class="align-r" scope="col">Start</th>
          <th class="align-r" scope="col">Win margin</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">1</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Canada"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Canada.png" alt="Canada flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-canadian-grand-prix/">Canada</a></td>
          <td>Montreal</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">4.343s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">2</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="USA"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/United-States.png" alt="USA flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-united-states-grand-prix/">USA</a></td>
          <td>Indianapolis</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">1.518s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">3</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Hungary"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Hungary.png" alt="Hungary flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-hungarian-grand-prix/">Hungary</a></td>
          <td>Hungaroring</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">0.715s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">4</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Japan"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Japan.png" alt="Japan flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-japanese-grand-prix/">Japan</a></td>
          <td>Fuji</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">8.377s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">5</th>
          <td>2008</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Australia"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Australia.png" alt="Australia flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2008-world-championship/2008-australian-grand-prix/">Australia</a></td>
          <td>Melbourne</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-23</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">5.478s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">6</th>
          <td>2008</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Monaco"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Monaco.png" alt="Monaco flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2008-world-championship/2008-monaco-grand-prix/">Monaco</a></td>
          <td>Monte Carlo</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-23</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="third-hl align-r">3</td>
          <td class="align-r">3.064s</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just tried this out and it works as intended. I assume your script is better than what I had before, and quicker?

Comment: I don't know about quicker, but it uses more modern JS techniques which will hopefully simplify your workflow a little. For example, it doesn't rely on you having to check each cell index individually as the `forEach` will do that for you., so you if you add a new column, this code will still work.

Comment: Awesome, perfect. I very much appreciate your help, especially the comments you added to the code as they help to see what's happening. Thanks, Andy!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use `var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent.toUpperCase();`

```js
function searchFilter(event) {
  var filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  var rows = document.querySelector("#filterTable tbody").rows;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var secondCol = rows[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    //var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var fourthCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var sixthCol = rows[i].cells[5].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var seventhCol = rows[i].cells[6].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var eighthCol = rows[i].cells[7].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (secondCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || thirdCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || fourthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || sixthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || seventhCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || eighthCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      rows[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('#driverSearch').addEventListener('keyup', searchFilter, false);
```

```html
<section id="chronology">
  <h2 id="chronology">Chronology</h2>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" id="driverSearch" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <table class="chronology sortable full-width" id="filterTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Year</th>
          <th scope="col">Grand Prix</th>
          <th scope="col">Circuit</th>
          <th scope="col">Race No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Constructor</th>
          <th scope="col">Chassis</th>
          <th scope="col">Engine</th>
          <th class="align-r" scope="col">Start</th>
          <th class="align-r" scope="col">Win margin</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">1</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Canada"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Canada.png" alt="Canada flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-canadian-grand-prix/">Canada</a></td>
          <td>Montreal</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">4.343s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">2</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="USA"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/United-States.png" alt="USA flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-united-states-grand-prix/">USA</a></td>
          <td>Indianapolis</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">1.518s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">3</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Hungary"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Hungary.png" alt="Hungary flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-hungarian-grand-prix/">Hungary</a></td>
          <td>Hungaroring</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">0.715s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">4</th>
          <td>2007</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Japan"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Japan.png" alt="Japan flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2007-world-championship/2007-japanese-grand-prix/">Japan</a></td>
          <td>Fuji</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-22</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">8.377s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">5</th>
          <td>2008</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Australia"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Australia.png" alt="Australia flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2008-world-championship/2008-australian-grand-prix/">Australia</a></td>
          <td>Melbourne</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-23</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="first-hl align-r">1</td>
          <td class="align-r">5.478s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header" scope="row">6</th>
          <td>2008</td>
          <td sorttable_customkey="Monaco"><img src="https://gpracingstats.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Monaco.png" alt="Monaco flag" class="flag" width="24" height="16" /> <a href="https://gpracingstats.com/seasons/2008-world-championship/2008-monaco-grand-prix/">Monaco</a></td>
          <td>Monte Carlo</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>McLaren</td>
          <td>MP4-23</td>
          <td>Mercedes V8</td>
          <td class="third-hl align-r">3</td>
          <td class="align-r">3.064s</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I thought I'd tried that but I guess not. Thanks for your help, much appreciated. :)